# Convolution filter returns partly black image, where am I going wrong here? Need to build a blurring filter from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, convolution

I have the following function:

```
def convolve(image, kernel):
    image_copy=image.copy()
    row=0
    column=0
    while column<image_copy.shape[0] and row<image_copy.shape[1]:
        image_copy[row:row+len(kernel),column:column+len(kernel)]*=kernel
        column+=1
        if column==len(image_copy):
            row+=1
            column=0
    return image_copy
```

When tested with the following:

```
kernel=np.ones((3,3))*1/9
kernel=kernel.astype('uint8')
convolve_image = convolve(image,kernel)
plt.imshow(convolve_image)
```

It returns this:
[image]

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Theres two parts to this:

1. Looking at the black square you switched rows and columns
2. In a convolution the source is always the original image. You pick your pixel and the 3x3 square around it, multiply it with the kernel and then sum it all up. That is your new pixel value you can write to your copy. What you do instead is multiplying every pixel in your image with 1/9 nine times which comes out as black.
3. If you use a colored image you should to account for the different channels, thios onyl works because of clever broadcasting numpy does. I wrote it more explicit.
4. If you convert your kernel thats floats < 1 to integers your kernel will be all zeros. Loose the conversion and only convert the whole picture at the end.

Your loop should look something like this:

```
def convolve(image, kernel):
    image_copy=image.copy()
    row=0
    column=0
    while row<image_copy.shape[0]-len(kernel)+1 and column<image_copy.shape[1]-len(kernel)+1:
        image_copy [row,column] = np.sum(image[row:row+len(kernel),column:column+len(kernel)]*kernel, axis=(0,1))
        column+=1
        if column==image_copy.shape[1]-len(kernel):
            row+=1
            column=0
return image_copy.astype('uint8')

kernel=np.ones((3,3,3))*1/9
#kernel=kernel.astype('uint8') <-this caues the black parts
convolve_image = convolve(image,kernel)
plt.imshow(convolve_image)
```

Note that this doesnt use any padding strategy and will move all your pixel up and left by one and leave a two pixel wide strip around the right and bottom edge. You might also run into issues using other kernel sizes than 3, since they will access areas outside the image and cause a mismatch in the kernel and value multiplication.

Comment: This didn't fix the issue of half the image being cut off, it just changed it to gray instead

Comment: yes and no, the fix does fix the cutoff but also need to be applied to `len(image_copy)` which is the wrong dimension again. I also caught another small bug, edit will follow shortly.

Comment: @liatkatz did that fix your issue?